# Text contains some sort of space

Tags: html, css, sass

I wonder how you would remove the space around text, I know this can be achieved by line-height. But space is always kept either above or below the text. Is there some dynamic way to do this? Either plain CSS or SASS works for me.

[image: white space around text]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: margin and padding can also do this: could you show us the styles applied?

Comment: Please go and read this https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ header elements have margin set up by default within browsers a simple h1{margin:0;} will get rid of it.

Comment: Are you talking about the the orange space or the blue space?

Comment: Honestly - what do you expect line-height to do? Are you confused by the concept or what exactly is the problem? You are aware that you need some space around the text for ascending/descending characters (e.g. like Â or g)? http://smad.jmu.edu/shen/webtype/lineheight.html

Comment: There are many reasons why that text could be there. We need to see your code to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your developer console tells you which property is responsible for the space.

[image]

In your case its the margin that is defined on the element. A simple

```
h1{
  margin:0;
}
```

will fix this.

In case you wonder, where this margin comes from - some of the elements, like headings come with predefined margins & paddings that are applied by the browsers automatically. In this case, the source in the `styles` section of your webdev console states "user agent stylesheet".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

write CSS

```
h1 {
margin: 0;
}
```

It will remove the default `margin` for `h1` getting applied from browser.

Comment: When you negate an answer, atleast leave a comment, so that someone could improvise

Comment: Without knowing who downvoted I would say this is because it's basically a duplicate answer without any additional added value that discerns it from the other answers that where already present? I guess this was to encourage upvoting an already existing answer instead of adding a duplicate?

Comment: When i started writing there was only answer, the moment I my answer got updated, your answer was also available.